# minDate not set on date pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to date pickers and I need both to have the same options and set of dates. I have a `.each` to do this, but the minDate option is not set. I've had a look around and seen that the way to set this when using `beforeShowDay` is to add the option after the control has initialized, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

```
// Defines and manipulates the datepickers
job.dateControl = function() {
    var datepickers = $(".js-datepicker");
    datepickers.each(function () {
        var dateToday = new Date();
        $(this).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: false,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            beforeShowDay: function (d) {
                var dmy = "";
                if (d.getDate() < 10) dmy += "0";
                dmy += d.getDate();
                dmy += "/";
                if (d.getMonth() < 9) dmy += "0";
                dmy += (d.getMonth() + 1);
                dmy += "/";
                dmy += d.getFullYear();
                console.log(dmy + ' : ' + ($.inArray(dmy, job.unavailableDates)));

                if ($.inArray(dmy, job.unavailableDates) !== -1) {
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                } else {
                    return [true, "", "Available"];
                }
            },
            minDate: dateToday
        });
        $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateToday);
    });
}
```

The 'job.unavailableDates' array containan array of UK bank holidays in the string format "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: Your code seems to be working (See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64y9eczp/1/)). Anything else that might be causing your issue?

Comment: That date picker in JS fiddle isn't working - the past dates are all available

Comment: Today is 28th September... But due to the `defaultDate` setting being +1w (+1 week) the calendar shows October.
If you click on the left arrow to go to the previous month you will see the days before 28th September disabled...